# How to resize column width according to data entered in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I am using `Guriddo jqGrid`. I have tried `autoResizable:true` and `autoresizeOnLoad: true` options in `colmodel` but still not working.Please suggest me is there any way to resize the width of the column.

Comment: `autoResizable:true` and `autoresizeOnLoad: true` are options of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork and not of commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Auto-adjustment-of-the-width-of-column) of free jqGrid.

Comment: So how it can be done in commercial jqgrid?

Comment: I develop "free jqGrid" fork and have no relation to Guriddo jqGrid. I wrote the implementation of auto-adjustment of the width of column in free jqGrid. I'm not sure that the functionality exists in Guriddo at all.

Comment: Currently this feature is not supported inGuriddo jqGrid. It is added in our todo list for the next release